# Rotate arrowheads in radarplot with Canvas

Tags: php, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to add arrowheads to my radar/spider plot coded in Canvas. Because I use PHP/SQL to retrieve some database values I echo most of the needed JS to plot it on the Canvas. So far I have drawn the axis (7) and guidelines (5 values).

How can I rotate the arrowheads so they show up correctly; with an angle and at the end of the 7 axis?

```
function drawArrows(context){
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "#ccc";
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.save();
<?php
$arrowHoek = 35;
$cHoek = (360/7);
$arrowLength = 10;

for ($i = 1 ; $i < 8 ; $i++) {
    $arrow_xleft = round((getCoordinates($i,6,x))-(sin(deg2rad($arrowHoek))*$arrowLength),2);
    $arrow_yleft = round((getCoordinates($i,6,y))+(cos(deg2rad($arrowHoek))*$arrowLength),2);
    $arrow_xright = round((getCoordinates($i,6,x))+(sin(deg2rad($arrowHoek))*$arrowLength),2);
    $arrow_yright = $arrow_yleft;
    $arrow_rotation = deg2rad(($cHoek*$i)-$cHoek);      

    echo "\tcontext.moveTo(";   
    getCoordinates($i,6,null);
    echo ");\n";
    echo "\tcontext.lineTo($arrow_xleft, $arrow_yleft);";
    echo "\n\tcontext.moveTo(";
    getCoordinates($i,6,null);
    echo ");\n";
    echo "\tcontext.lineTo($arrow_xright, $arrow_yright);\n";
    echo "\tcontext.rotate($arrow_rotation);\n";
    echo "\tcontext.restore();\n";
    echo "\tcontext.save();\n"; 

} 
?>
context.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I worked it out! As found in other topics this uses the save(), translate(), rotate() and restore() functions. If you put this in a seperate Javascript function you can make transformations to individual Canvas parts without messing up any other drawings.

Below is the solution (note this uses PHP to echo the Javascript function).

```
function drawArrows(context){
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "#ccc";
context.lineWidth = 2;
<?php
$arrowHoek = 35;
$cHoek = (360/7);
$arrowLength = 10;

for ($i = 1 ; $i < 8 ; $i++) {
    $arrow_xleft = -(sin(deg2rad($arrowHoek))*$arrowLength);
    $arrow_yleft = (cos(deg2rad($arrowHoek))*$arrowLength);
    $arrow_xright = (sin(deg2rad($arrowHoek))*$arrowLength);
    $arrow_yright = $arrow_yleft;
    $arrow_rotation = deg2rad(($cHoek*$i)-$cHoek);  

    echo "\tcontext.save();\n";
    echo "\tcontext.translate(";    
    getCoordinates($i,6,null);
    echo ");\n";
    echo "\tcontext.rotate($arrow_rotation);\n";
    echo "\tcontext.moveTo($arrow_xleft, $arrow_yleft);";
    echo "\n\tcontext.lineTo(0,0);\n";
    echo "\tcontext.lineTo($arrow_xright, $arrow_yright);\n";
    echo "\tcontext.restore();\n";
} 
?>
context.stroke();
}
```

- Note: The declaration of the context and canvas elements are in a container function.